# How check affected db row after perform mockMvc in spring mvc integration test

Tags: java, spring, testing, tdd, integration-testing

I have Integration test for controller method in spring mvc by SpringJUnit4ClassRunner:

```
@Test
public void testUpdateSuccess() throws Exception {
    Integer pageId = 2;
    RequestBuilder request = post("/admin/page/update/"+pageId)
            .param("id", pageId.toString())
            .param("title", "page title 2 edited")
            .param("content", "page content 2 edited")
            .with(csrf());

mockMvc.perform(request)
            .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.flash().attribute("message", "Successfully updated!"));
}
```

**1-** How can I test if above test updated related database row?

**2-** Is it good to test if database updated Appropriately inside above test?